# Save UIImage as png from another thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin.ios, uiimage

The code is pretty easy, it has to load from a settings file all the existing images references, scale them to 250x250 and save them with another name.

The problem is that on the device (tested on an iPhone 3g and an iPad) it crashes after a while with memory warnings.  On the simulator it's working perfect.

I have a UIViewController which has on ViewDidAppear this code:

```
ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem( delegate{ 
    make_thumbs(); 
});
```

The make_thumbs function is:

```
void make_thumbs() 
{ 
    using( var ns = new NSAutoreleasePool() ) 
    { 
        foreach( var c in Settings.Instance.Categories ) 
        { 
            for( var i = 0; i < c.Pictures.Count; i++ ) 
            { 
                //this is the existing bundled image path 
                string     path = c.Pictures[i].PicturePath; 
                string   folder = Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal ); 
                //this is the destination image file name 
                string filename = Path.Combine( folder, c.Name + i + ".png"); 
                if( !File.Exists( filename ) ) 
                { 
                    NSError err;
                    using(UIImage img = UIImage.FromFile( path ).Scale( 250,250 ))
                    {
                        img.AsPNG().Save( filename, true, out err );
                    }
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: I am not sure what the problem is, however there is a performance tweak you can apply to your code. MonoTouch creates an NSAutoReleasePool object for ThreadPool threads, so there is no need for you to create one. Info here: http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/advanced_topics/threading?highlight=Thread

Comment: You might want to try disposing the result of AsPNG when done with it. With the latest MonoDevelop + MonoTouch beta there is also a profiler you can use to try to figure out what's leaking.

Comment: `string   folder = Environment.GetFolderPath( Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal );` is an invariant and should be moved outside the loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thx @poupou, it was almost good your answer, with a little completion: i had to put the 
using( var ns = new NSAutoreleasePool() ) inside the for loop.  So my code is now like this and it's working:

```
if( !File.Exists( filename ) )
{
    using( var ns = new NSAutoreleasePool() )
    {
        NSError err;
        using(UIImage img = UIImage.FromFile( path )) {
            using (var scaled_img = img.Scale( 250,250 )) 
            {
                //i also add a reflection effect                             
                using( var reflected_img = scaled_img.AddImageReflection( 0.6f ) )
                {
                    using (var data = reflected_img.AsPNG ()) 
                    {
                        data.Save( filename, true, out err );
                    }
                }
             }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to *extend* my suggestion (from the [mailing-list](http://lists.ximian.com/pipermail/monotouch/2012-January/007735.html)) for everything that implements `IDisposable` inside your loop (since it can allocate memory much more quickly than the GC will be able to collect it).

Like @Rolf said, in the comments, `img.AsPNG()` returns an `NSData` which implements `IDisposable`.

Also calling the `Scale` method also returns a new `UIImage`.

```
 using(UIImage img = UIImage.FromFile( path )) {
     using (var scaled_img = img.Scale( 250,250 )) {
         using (var data = img.AsPNG ()) {
             data.Save( filename, true, out err );
         }
     }
 }
```

That should cover this block, i.e. ensure all memory is reclaimed as soon as possible, which should help your device (not a lot of memory available in them).